# MySQL select rows older then a week

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL, how can I select only rows which are older than a week?

I need to do this to make a system which removes old tmp files which I have stored in the database.

Comment: What is you database schema?

Comment: Yes please, need more information about the schema

Comment: It should be possible to provide an answer to this basic sql question without needing to see a schema.

Comment: This question has too many duplicates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this,

```
select * from table
where DATEDIFF(now(),colname) > 7;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table
where (SELECT DATEDIFF(curtime(),col_name)) > 7
```

Comment: Isnt it should be less than 7?

Comment: no, col_name and curtime() need a swap

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `created` < dateadd(week,-1,getdate())
```

Comment: Nice but the question is tagged with "mysql".

Comment: Maybe they were using MySQL?